# Stange behaviour in store procedure execution, only sp_recompile helps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I noticed strange behavior in store procedure execution in sql server. Suddenly it takin longer time with no end. SP getting called from another server through SSIS package. SP is without input parameters, so we cannot expect parameter sniffing here. But SP uses temp variables to declare a table. It might possibility that missing statistics from temp variable may cause sudden change in execution plan and sp run slow.

But then why only recompiling SP is helping here. Every day I have to recompile sp before it runs otherwise it showing same behavior, run longer and longer (no end).

My question is: why is `sp_recompile` required to run sp quick every day?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-recompile-transact-sql  The queries used by stored procedures, or triggers, and user-defined functions are optimized only when they are compiled. As indexes or other changes that affect statistics are made to the database, compiled stored procedures, triggers, and user-defined functions may lose efficiency. By recompiling stored procedures and triggers that act on a table, you can reoptimize the queries.

Comment: I have this, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of some of my queries that I know need to be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use with recompile hint, but I would strongly recommend (Since recompiling a stored procedure puts a load on the server and also if execution plan cache is full every recompilation would cause dropping of one of the cached execution plans, which can lead to dropping of good execution plans.) try and observe execution plan changing to find out why the execution plan become inefficient.